# Uploading all CSV files in a directory to Google Cloud

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, directory

I'm trying to upload all CSV files within a certain directory to a Google Cloud project. I was previously doing it like this:

```
<include path="/my/path/**.csv" />
```

However, for reasons unrelated to this question, I had to change my file structure such that the .csv files are now nested inside of different folders within /my/path/.

A picture to clarify:

Old setup: path -> {.csv files}
New setup: path -> {one -> {.csv files}, two -> {.csv files}, ...}

If I want to upload all of the .csv files in the same way that I was doing before, how would I structure the call such that it recursively uploads all files nested in the sub-directories? Thanks so much!

Edit:

Would `<include path="/parsing/wiki/**/**.csv" />` work?

Comment: please add which Google Cloud services you are using to upload it and the full command  (e.g. if Storage, `gsutil cp ...`) that may characterize that this question is related to Google Cloud Platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<include path="/parsing/wiki/**/**.csv" />
```

This works as I intended it to.